# Why is Noble Hierarch so expensive?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Noble Hierarch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Noble%20Hierarch) costs {G}, is a 0/1 Human Druid with exalted, and taps for {G}, {W}, or {U}.

[Birds of Paradise](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Birds%20of%20Paradise) costs {G}, is a 0/1 Bird with flying, and taps for one of any color.

Noble Hierarch is $40-$50, Birds of Paradise is $5.

Why? The birds have flying, and can tap for {R} or {B}.

The exalted doesn't seem like it would be applicable here.

Comment: What do you mean with "The exalted doesn't seem like it would be applicable here."?

Comment: In most decks, the objective is lots of creatures swinging with each. I didn't consider Infect.

Comment: That is a very narrow view of Magic. If you look at the 12 most common Legacy decks, for example, only 6 of them work like that, if you're counting generously.

Comment: @murgatroid99 how does one determine the 12 most common legacy decks?

Comment: I looked at the [mtggoldfish Legacy metagame page](http://www.mtggoldfish.com/metagame/legacy#paper).

Comment: I remember a time when Birds of Paradise was a lot more expensive. Prices can change for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at how much each has been printed. [Noble Hierarch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Noble%20Hierarch) was printed in Conflux and Modern Masters. [Birds of Paradise](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Birds%20of%20Paradise) was printed in Alpha/Beta/Unlimited/Revised, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, and 10th edition, Magic 2010, 2011, 2012, and Ravnica. There are just way, way more copies out there.

And by the way, Exalted can be quite relevant. The most obvious example is Infect ([quite popular](http://www.mtggoldfish.com/metagame/modern#paper) and [can win tournaments](http://sales.starcitygames.com//deckdatabase/displaydeck.php?DeckID=101065)), which is likely to play only Noble Hierarch and not Birds of Paradise. It doesn't need the other colors of mana, flying isn't that important, but an extra poison counter here or there is a huge deal. But this is true even for decks that aren't as all-in on single creatures. For example, [this Zoo list](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/daily-deck/modern-naya-zoo-2015-11-06) plays Noble Hierarch and not Birds of Paradise. It has plenty of other ways to get the red mana, and even if sometimes it attacks with multiple creatures (missing out on exalted), the extra damage on the turns when it only has one creature to attack with can make a huge difference.

Comment: Beat me by a minute, better answer to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Two things affect the price of a card.

The card utility, and the card rarity.

[Noble Hierarch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Noble%20Hierarch) has very few copies in circulation relative to [Birds of Paradise](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Birds%20of%20Paradise).  So that will affect the price.  Additionally, Exalted is hugely important in a number of decks.  Most notably infect.

Comment: Damn, Jefromi types way faster than me...

Answer (score 0):

It wins goyf (i.e. [Tarmogoyf](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tarmogoyf)) battles. Something that birds of paradise does nothing for. In the Abzan mirror for instance it is crucial in getting your goyfs over your opponents creatures.

Goyfs have one toughness more than their power so they can easily have a staring contest where it makes no sense to attack into one (With your own.) The exalted trigger breaks the stalemate.  Your goyf will kill your opponent's if he blocks and if he doesn't and there are no other creatures in play you are winning the race.

It does not really ramp per se in these decks. It does help fixing a bit but still that free exalted triggers is crucial in getting your creatures trough.